# Symfony2 on shared hosting without APC - so slow

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, apc

My symfony2/doctrine2 site is ready for production so I uploaded it to my shared (TSOHost) cloud server. They dont have APC activated and the site is super slow.

On my local env, pages take ~180ms to load with APC enabled and that doubles when I disable APC.

On the shared host the same pages take ~2 seconds to load and often hangs completely. My product listing page sometimes takes >30 seconds for the ajax request to load all the products!

It feels like doctrine is especially struggling.

My host can only suggest I move to a dedicated virtual server, which is obviously more expensive, but I dont want to do that unless I can be sure its going to resolve the problem.

Is this down to the lack of APC? Do I have any alternatives to APC?

Comment: I had a considerably simple symfony project on shared hosting time ago - it was slow as hell. Symfony is designed to be run in an environment you can have control on, otherwise even basic deploying would be a nightmare.

Comment: So in the end I moved the site to a dedicated virtual server, and wow, what a difference. The thing is flying! After some rudimentary tests I would say its almost faster than my local machine (I7 8gb ram). Im just praying the VPS will handle the traffic spikes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is:

http://slides.seld.be/?file=2011-10-20+High+Performance+Websites+with+Symfony2.html#21

Symfony2 is fast and lightweight but in heavy category.
I've always cache the forms because form generation takes a years(with APC on). Look at this presentation and find some clues.

Comment: start from a very beginning of that presentation :)

Comment: Ive had a quick read over the presentation and while it suggests a number of enhancements I can implement, I get the impression that without APC Im not going to get anywhere near the performance I need. Is that a fair conclusion?

Comment: More less yes. You got the bootstrap.php.cache file generated by symfony and it's loaded to the APC. If you have rights(sudo) you can try place this file on the RAMDisk. But i think that if you have sudo you will be able to install APC on you own.